# how to import bookmarks for brave browser from windows.old folder?

Tags: browser, import, windows-backup

i have reinstalled my OS. I have windows.old folder and need to import bookmarks for brave browser.

Is it even there in the backup folder? or the brave's settings are lost after reinstalling?

Comment: Chrome stores bookmarks in the "C:\Users\<Your User name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" folder, brave is chrome based, so look for that default folder in the Windows.old folder, copy the bookmarks file into the new location. See if that works.

Comment: @Moab, i found it, but facint another problem - can't import it. it 's a json file inside , i changed it's dimension to html for brave to see it - it can see it now, i press import and nothing happens..

Comment: I dont use the import function in chrome, I just copy and paste the file, this is how I back up settings for chrome. Brave may store settings like bookmarks differently, I don't know.

Comment: @Moab, how do i copy 300 urls?

Comment: @Moab, i mean how can i copy 300 urls from file - add 1 by 1 ?